# Angular 8 library load feature module after receiving data

Tags: angular, angular-google-maps

Currently I'm working on a library project in Angular 8. The library project consists of a main module, and a set of submodules. My library is used in a client where a customers logs in and gets an apiKey from the backend. This apiKey has to be used in the forRoot method of one of the submodules (Angular google maps). There is no router available in my library project, so lazy loading is difficult. My library is always eagerly loaded in the client.

Is there a way to load the submodule (Angular google maps) after the Apikey is fetched from the backend?